# How to manage dependencies for a Php application?

Tags: php, build, dependencies, installation, libraries

I have a php application that requires that the server that it runs in has *php5-imagick* and *php5-mcrypt* installed and enabled. What kind of tool can I use that will look if those two are installed or not and if it is not then install them? I don't what these tools are called that is why I am not being very specific? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not sure how to specifically look for versioning, but I have tried looking for a function or class that I know my code requires using `function_exists("functionname")` or `class_exists("classname")`. To install, you would have to have server admin privileges, I reckon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use composer, look up the documentation at https://getcomposer.org/

Once installed you can create a composer.json file in the project root which defines exactly what you need in order for the application to run. For example:

```
{
    "name": "Foo\Bar",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.4.0",
        "ext-imagick": "*"
    }
}
```

Then run: Composer install

It'll tell you if the dependencies in the "require" section haven't been met. You'd still have to install php5-* things manually but it's a good guide.